# wallet: cartera vs. billetera

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, sinónimos, vocabulario

The English word "wallet" (as in something you carry in your pocket to hold money, credit cards, etc.) can be translated into Spanish as *cartera* or *billetera*. Are the words synonyms that can be used interchangeably, or does each country generally use one word or the other? If it is a regional difference, what areas of the Spanish-speaking world generally use each word?

Comment: Billetera is the one i’m likely to remember more so i’d Go for the one you can remember more easily since there are a lot of different ways to say things on Spanish anyway like sencillo and simple

Comment: What I have seen in at least parts of Mexico: *Cartera* for wallet or coin purse; *bolsa, bolso* for bag or purse.  ("Purse" is a lot bigger than a "coin purse" in the US -- and in fact, "coin purse" is hardly used these days.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a regional choice, as with many other nouns.

In Chile, *billetera* is the only translation of *wallet* (though we would understand the use of *cartera* from a foreign person), but *cartera* is actually *purse*, as in handbag: a bag a woman uses to carry stuff, which is usually much bigger than a wallet and does not fit in a pocket.

In other countries, words like *bolsa* and *bolso* are used for *purse*, while *cartera* is used for *wallet*.

My guess is that *cartera* is more widespread, because it is also the origin of *carterista* (pickpocket), which is more standard. If you intend to translate the word for a global audience, you should go for *cartera*.

Comment: In Spain: for wallet: cartera, for purse: monedero and for handbag: bolso.

Comment: +1 Same in Argentina.

Answer (score 7):

In Colombia, the word `cartera` is mostly used to refer to a woman's [Bolso](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=bolso) (handbag).

I should mention that `cartera` is falling out of use in Colombia. I can only remember old people using that word. `Bolso` is the preferred word nowadays.

I am almost certain that in other Latin American countries (Argentina comes to mind) the words `cartera` and `billetera` mean the same; in other words, a man can say: `Se me olvidó mi cartera` but you wouldn't hear that coming from a male in Colombia.

Comment: I disagree with the falling out of use in Colombia. Maybe in some regions but not in Cali or Bogota that I know of.

Comment: In Argentina the two words don't mean the same, we use cartera for purse and billetera for wallet.

Comment: @Joze Regardless of which term is more usual, I think that "bolso" is very usual in Colombia with the meaning of "handbag"? It seemed so to me while I was in the country.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I agree, Bolso is usual, I'm just saying that cartera is on the same level.